# Cumulative sum of month if given days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My table is as follows

```
T1 (date int, dateYearMonth int, userID int, shopID int, amount numeric(18,2))
```

example data:

```
(20151212, 201512, 1, 1, 50.00),
(20151213, 201512, 1, 1, 30.00),
(20160110, 201601, 1, 1, 13.00)
```

I would like to return cumulative sums of each month for user,
my query is:

```
select t.dateYearMonth, t.userID,
sum(t.sum_amount) over
(partition by t.userID order by t.dateYearMonth
 rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from (select dateYearMonth, userID, sum(amount) as sum_amount FROM T1
group by dateYearMonth, userID) t
```

Is there more optimal way to do this?
output expected

```
(201512, 1, 1, 80.00), (201601, 1, 1, 93.00)
```

Comment: Why `93.00` for `201601`?

Comment: this is cumulative sum - it is rising over the months (previous value + current value)

Comment: Try recursive CTE and compare performance with your approach. Recursive cte should also work with earlier version of SQL Server.

Comment: It is quite unlikely you would find a more optimized method when comparing to the analytic functions such as sum() over(). Recursive CTEs may be competitive depending on scale but doubt it can be faster at large scale.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dateYearMonth, userID
       ,total = SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY dateYearMonth)
FROM T1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/YCTZ27832)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is pretty good as is. I don't think it can be made any better.

Make sure that you have a covering index, like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX] ON T1
(
    userID ASC
    ,dateYearMonth ASC
) INCLUDE(amount);
```

With this index the execution plan for the temp table with your sample data looks like this:

[image: execution plan]

It just reads all rows from the table (index) and groups/sums them without extra sorting.